# mysql query to find students with combinations of classes

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table with 2 fields.  Student_id and Course_id
A particular Student_ID could take multiple courses e.g., student 2 is taking courses 101 and 102 in the example below, but student 1 is taking only 102

```
student_id  course_id
1             102
2             101
2             102
3             303
```

How would I query for students that are taking courses 101 AND 102?  Or a student that is taking 102 but not taking 101?

Probably a newbie question for you experts...

Answer (score 1):

This one maybe?

```
Select * from tablename where (course_id = 101) OR (course_id = 102);
```

to check someone who is in 101 and not 102

```
select * from tablename 
      where (course_id = 101) and 
            (student_Id not in 
                 (select Student_ID from tablename 
                                where course_id =102));
```

to check if someone is in both:

```
select * from tablename 
          where (course_id = 101) and 
                (student_Id in 
                     (select student_Id from tablename 
                                    where course_id =102));
```

### [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca731/3)

Comment: This would return all students in either 101 or 102. He asked for students in both, and students in one or the other...

Comment: @JesseShellabarger edited to add answer

Comment: I don't think this works.  The objective is to return student_id 2 for a query on students who are taking course_id 101 AND 102.  I ran it on [link] http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0223b7/24  and it returned Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: @Coding Enthusiast:  I am new here...apparently an upvote needs a 15 reputation, so supposedly I can't :-(

Comment: you have to clidk on the tick under my answer ) to accept it